# I got an error when I use to open view controller :- EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Tags: swift

I use tab bar in view controller but when I run project and then tap on complaint tab it shows me error like

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.63/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178

Please tell me how to solve this error.

```
import UIKit
class ComplaintViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mytableview: UITableView!
    ////step->1
    var ComplaintList:[Complaint]?
    var complaint:Complaint?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        requestForProductList()
        mytableview.reloadData()// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    private func requestForProductList() {
        ///step->2
        var c_url = const_url + ("complaint_view.php")
        let url = URL(string:c_url)
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (result, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            let resultDict = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result!, options: .allowFragments)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parseData(result: resultDict as! [String : Any])
            }
            print(resultDict)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    private func parseData(result:[String:Any]) {
        ///step->3
        let complaintMain = ComplaintMain(fromDictionary: result)
        ComplaintList = complaintMain.complaint
        mytableview.reloadData()
    }
    //MARK:- Tableview datasource methods
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let list = ComplaintList {
            return list.count
        }
        return 0
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mycell", for:indexPath) as! ComplaintTableViewCell
        let complaint = ComplaintList?[indexPath.row]
        cell.lbltype.text = complaint?.ctype
        let reqUrl = URL(string: const_url + (complaint?.url)!)
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: reqUrl!)
        if data != nil
        {
            cell.myimage.image =  UIImage(data:data as! Data)
        }
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        complaint = ComplaintList?[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "select", sender: nil)
    }
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let vc3 = segue.destination as! ComplaintdidselectViewController
        vc3.complaint = complaint 
    }
}
```

Comment: The `result` you obtain from the data task isn't actually JSON data.

Comment: so what should i do

Comment: Stop using `try!`, `as!`, and other forced unwrapping and do proper error checking. Then you can look at `result` and see what (non-JSON) data you are actually getting back. Most likely your POST is incorrect and the server is returning some error.